# Python command for selecting bone groups

Tags: python, bones

So I wanted to create a python script to make my animation workflow quicker. So I made a script and it works great. But then I thought about making a pop-up menu for it. I found a tutorial online that showed me how to do it but in his example, he used the command:   **layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")**

I tried it out and it worked fine. But I don't want to use the add cube command in my script. Instead, I want to change the active bone group on my armature object but I can't find the command for doing so.

How would I find that command? I tried looking in the info window, but the command that shows up there results in a bunch of errors.

Comment: Convert your script to an operator (see examples in text editor python templates) give it a `bl_idname` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: What do you mean "Bob's your uncle"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle